# Ошибка re.sub: "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object"

Tags: python, python-3.x, re

```
import re
mystr = ['234egfdgf']
mystr = re.sub(r"[egfdgf]", "", mystr)
```

Ошибка:

```
return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Должно работать

Comment: А `mystr` случайно стал списком или так и нужно было?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто уберите mystr из квадратных скобок:

```
mystr = '234egfdgf'
```